# Automapper Mapping Arraylist

Tags: c#, automapper

I have the following class:

```
public class Response{
    public string Result {get;set;}
    public ArrayList Errors {get;set;}
}
```

and the following mappings

```
cfg.CreateMap<ErrorMessage, Error>();

cfg.CreateMap<OriginalResponse, Response>()
   .ForMember(d => d.Errors, 
              opts => opts.MapFrom(s => s.ErrorMessages));
```

In my source, `ErrorMessages` is an Array of type `ErrorMessage`.

I would like like the `Errors` ArrayList in my response to be of type `Error` but my mapping is returning an ArrayList of type `ErrorMessage` (the original type).

How could I get the ArrayList to map correctly?

I can't use a regular array of type `Errors` because of the limitations of a 3rd party system.

Repro here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/VPRsYV

Comment: Who is teaching the use of `ArrayList` in .net these days?

Comment: @TheGeneral being forced to use ArrayList in a 3rd party system unfortunately

Comment: You might have to create a TypeConverter http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-type-converters.html

Comment: You don't need a type converter. That works for me using the latest from NuGet. A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Comment: It works for me but the ArrayList is of the source type (`ErrorMessage`) and not the destination type (`Error`)

Comment: No, I meant it's `Error`. Show us a repro.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu see https://dotnetfiddle.net/VPRsYV I would expect type to be Error not SourceError

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

`cfg.CreateMap<ErrorMessage, Error>();
 cfg.CreateMap<ErrorMessage, object>().As<Error>();`

This tells AM that when you map from `ErrorMessage` to `object` (there is no element type information in `ArrayList`), you actually mean to `Error`. Check [the docs](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Mapping-inheritance.html).

Comment: Thanks, it is now of the correct type - but the properties of the mapped type are null. See https://dotnetfiddle.net/8R6QTj. Would I need to specify `.ForMember()` for each property that is mapped?

Comment: Updated. You're missing a map.